# Is it possible to add template trough angular.js from outside of ng-view?

Tags: angularjs

I want to have a login view outside ng-view, but is it even possible with angular.js? couldnt find any examples of folowing on the internet. Example is descibed below.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="loginView"> my huge login view</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use `ng-include` or create your own directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Assign a controller to the `loginView` and treat it like any other view.

`ng-view` is just used when using the `$routeProvider` to define routes.

Comment: OP stated: *I want to have a login view outside ng-view*, so not sure if your answer is what he asked for

Comment: assigning a controller helped me

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly valid. [ngView](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive%3angView) is used to complement the router. This means it is just a directive as any other. You can put anything around it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like this: **[Live demo here (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/NB1clFnKHXWzBanl951c?p=preview)**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="loginView" ng-include="'login.html'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also include your file from a `$scope` property like this:

```
$scope.foo = 'login.html';
```

`<div ng-include="foo"></div>`

Comment: Do not forget that ng-include creates a new scope